# Matching all characters until a specific word (in this case an html tag) with Regex

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I'm not very good with regex, but I found this code:

```
<?php
$string = "some text (a(b(c)d)e) more text";
if(preg_match("/\((?>[^()]+|(?R))*\)/",$string,$matches))
{
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($matches); echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```

And I'm trying to change the regex pattern to match opening and closing html tags instead of parenthesis, but I cant figure out how to mimic `"[^()]+"` so that it matches tags instead of parenthesis.

The purpose of this would be to allow me to make a new html tag, whose contents I can access regardless of how many times the tag is nested within itself. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[^()]` defines [character class](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php). `^` means "everything but following characters". So your example can be interpreted as *everything except brackets*.

If you're parsing content of html tag you require `[^<>]+`.

If you have content like `<div>Blah <a>foo</a>bar</div>` and you want to match `Blah <a>foo</a>bar` you should use regexp like `~<div>(.+?)</div>~`

`?` after quantifier is called [greedy killer](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#What-does-it-mean-that-regexes-are-greedy?-How-can-I-get-around-it?)  and it'll make sure regexp "stops eating" when it encouters `</div`

Anyway... You should rather use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and [`xPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)`::`[`query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) when parsing HTML. Here's some [random tutorial](http://ditio.net/2008/12/01/php-xpath-tutorial-advanced-xml-part-1/) from google.

Comment: the example with <div>Blah <a>foo</a>bar</div> would suit my needs better if it could accurately parse <div>Blah <div>foo</div>bar</div> but thanks for the info about DOM, ill look into it

Comment: @Max DOM will have better performance and all... I may add example of parsing it if you want to...